# How Serving Web Apps Work

Tags: web-services, networking, web-applications, hosting

I was wandering (because though I am a programmer I am not good with networking) if I have a site with multiple databases for user accounts, what unifies those servers/multiple databases so it doesn't check the wrong database or sever. So when I go from having 1 server to multiple, will I be able to keep the same application and the databases will expand into those server? If someone suggested a book that would be great!

Comment: Same application to be hosted in multiple servers (web farm scenario) and you want to connect multiple databases from the application - is my understanding correct?

Comment: One database just multiple servers so it doesn't crash with a lot of traffic

Comment: Same database spread across multiple servers, so I assume all read-only data (user accounts) - as long as it's read-only I think it should be fine. Otherwise a data sync up is  required.

Comment: Just curious, how are you switching between different database servers?

Comment: Well users make posts and things like that.

Answer (score 1):

Understanding how horizontal scaling works is concept which would give you clear understanding of how that's done.

I suggest you to read articles and books which related to that topic.

There are a lot of good books and articles related to that topic, few of them listed below:

- [Understanding Horizontal and Vertical Scaling](http://blakesmith.me/2012/12/08/understanding-horizontal-and-vertical-scaling.html)
- [Best Practices For Horizontal Application Scaling](https://blog.openshift.com/best-practices-for-horizontal-application-scaling/)
- [Building Scalable Web Sites: Building, Scaling, and Optimizing the Next Generation of Web Applications 1st Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596102356)
- [4 Architecture Issues When Scaling Web Applications: Bottlenecks, Database, CPU, IO](http://highscalability.com/blog/2014/5/12/4-architecture-issues-when-scaling-web-applications-bottlene.html)